# Problema con lista de objetos desde archivo de texto plano en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema con la manipulación de la información de un archivo log de texto plano, intento guardar las propiedades de cada log del archivo en un modelo de c#, y luego guardar los modelos que hayan sido generados en una lista del mismo tipo, ya logro obtener y guardar la información en los modelos usando un ciclo, el problema es que si al final tenía guaradados 20 logs, la lista contendrá la misma cantidad pero en todos me muestra sólo la información del ultimo log, al actualizar el objeto con cada iteración todos los que se hayan guardado antes también se actualizan, busco una manera de que los datos una vez guardados se queden tal cual en la lista y continue así con los demás

Anexo lo que obtengo

```
GlobalVariables.ListMo
Count = 5
[0]: {ConsoleApp1.Modelos.Class1}
[1]: {ConsoleApp1.Modelos.Class1}
[2]: {ConsoleApp1.Modelos.Class1}
[3]: {ConsoleApp1.Modelos.Class1}
[4]: {ConsoleApp1.Modelos.Class1}


GlobalVariables.ListMo[0]
{ConsoleApp1.Modelos.Class1}
ClaseGeneradora: "DetalleUsuarioDataAccess"
DirectorioBase: "C:\\repositorio\\********\\******\\ "
FechaLog: "2018-08-13 16:46:56.1607 "
LugarDeLlamada: "BusinessLogic.Logs.DireccionamientoLogs.EscribirLogRegistro "
MensajeObtenido: "El usuario 2 realiz� un nuevo registr� en 'UsuarioDetalles' con el ID: 52 "
Tipo: "INFO "
GlobalVariables.ListMo[1]
{ConsoleApp1.Modelos.Class1}
ClaseGeneradora: "GuardarDetalle "
DirectorioBase: "C:\\repositorio\\************\\********\\ "
FechaLog: "2018-08-13 16:46:56.1607 "
LugarDeLlamada: "BusinessLogic.Logs.DireccionamientoLogs.EscribirLogRegistro "
MensajeObtenido: "El usuario 2 realiz� un nuevo registr� en 'UsuarioDetalles' con el ID: 52 "
Tipo: "INFO "
```

En todos está la misma información, pero cada uno tiene diferentes propiedades.

Estos son los métodos con los que leo y añado al modelo y a la lista

```
private List<Class1> ContenidoArchivo(string path)
    {
        StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(path);

        string linea = "";

        int cont = 0;

        while (linea != null)
        {
            linea = objReader.ReadLine();
            if (linea != null)
            {
                QuitarAtributos(linea);
                cont++;
            }

            if (cont ==6)
            {
                GlobalVariables.ListMo.Add(modelo);
                cont = 0;
            }
        }
        objReader.Close();
        return null;
    }
private void QuitarAtributos(string linea)`
    {

        if (linea.Contains("FechaLog:"))
        {
            modelo.FechaLog = linea.Replace("FechaLog:", "");
        }

        if (linea.Contains("Tipo:"))
        {
            modelo.Tipo = linea.Replace("Tipo:", "");
        }

        if (linea.Contains("ClaseGeneradora:"))
        {
            modelo.ClaseGeneradora = linea.Replace("ClaseGeneradora:", "");
        }

        if (linea.Contains("LugarDeLlamada:"))
        {
            modelo.LugarDeLlamada = linea.Replace("LugarDeLlamada:", "");
        }

        if (linea.Contains("MensajeObtenido:"))
        {
            modelo.MensajeObtenido = linea.Replace("MensajeObtenido:", "");
        }

        if (linea.Contains("DirectorioBase:"))
        {
            modelo.DirectorioBase = linea.Replace("DirectorioBase:", "");
        }

    }
```

Este es una vista de como está escrito el archivo

```
FechaLog:2018-08-13 16:01:36.3557 
Tipo:INFO 
ClaseGeneradora:GuardarUsuario 
LugarDeLlamada:BusinessLogic.Logs.DireccionamientoLogs.EscribirLogRegistro 
MensajeObtenido:El usuario 2 realizó un nuevo registró en 'Usuarios' con el ID: 123 
DirectorioBase:C:\repositorio\*******\*******\
FechaLog:2018-08-13 16:18:04.2844 
Tipo:INFO 
ClaseGeneradora:GuardarTipo 
LugarDeLlamada:BusinessLogic.Logs.DireccionamientoLogs.EscribirLogRegistro 
MensajeObtenido:El usuario 2 realizó un nuevo registró en 'TipoUsuarios' con el ID: 61 
DirectorioBase:C:\repositorio\*******\*******\ 
FechaLog:2018-08-13 16:40:11.2955 
Tipo:INFO 
ClaseGeneradora:GuardarRol 
LugarDeLlamada:BusinessLogic.Logs.DireccionamientoLogs.EscribirLogRegistro 
MensajeObtenido:El usuario 2 realizó un nuevo registró en 'RolUsuario' con el ID: 44 
DirectorioBase:C:\repositorio\*******\*******\
FechaLog:2018-08-13 17:01:37.0273 
Tipo:INFO 
ClaseGeneradora:GuardarUsuario 
LugarDeLlamada:BusinessLogic.Logs.DireccionamientoLogs.EscribirLogRegistro 
MensajeObtenido:El usuario 2 realizó un nuevo registró en 'Usuarios' con el ID: 126 
DirectorioBase:C:\repositorio\*******\*******\
FechaLog:2018-08-13 16:46:56.1607 
Tipo:INFO 
ClaseGeneradora:GuardarDetalle 
LugarDeLlamada:BusinessLogic.Logs.DireccionamientoLogs.EscribirLogRegistro 
MensajeObtenido:El usuario 2 realizó un nuevo registró en 'UsuarioDetalles' con el ID: 52 
DirectorioBase:C:\repositorio\*******\*******\
```

Gracias desde ahora

Comment: Muy posiblemente se deba a que estas referenciando al mismo modelo, cuando deberias de crear modelos nuevos por cada ciclo.
Nos apoyarias mejor con mas detalles de tu codigo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente estoy apuntando al mismo objeto, precisamente lo que busco es no generar tantos objetos, puesto que mi archivo puede contener n cantidad de logs (modelos), y básicamente ese es todo el código que manejo, el objeto es una instancia común Object obj = new Object();

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que siempre apuntas al mismo objeto 'modelo', intenta hacerlo así:

```
 private List<Class1> ContenidoArchivo(string path)
{
    StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(path);

    string linea = "";

    int cont = 0;

    while (linea != null)
    {
        linea = objReader.ReadLine();
        Modelo modelo = new Modelo();
        if (linea != null)
        {
            modelo = QuitarAtributos(linea);
            cont++;
        }

        if (cont ==6)
        {
            GlobalVariables.ListMo.Add(modelo);
            cont = 0;
        }
    }
    objReader.Close();
    return null;
}

 private Modelo QuitarAtributos(string linea)`
{
    Modelo modelo = new Modelo();
    if (linea.Contains("FechaLog:"))
    {
        modelo.FechaLog = linea.Replace("FechaLog:", "");
    }

    if (linea.Contains("Tipo:"))
    {
        modelo.Tipo = linea.Replace("Tipo:", "");
    }

    if (linea.Contains("ClaseGeneradora:"))
    {
        modelo.ClaseGeneradora = linea.Replace("ClaseGeneradora:", "");
    }

    if (linea.Contains("LugarDeLlamada:"))
    {
        modelo.LugarDeLlamada = linea.Replace("LugarDeLlamada:", "");
    }

    if (linea.Contains("MensajeObtenido:"))
    {
        modelo.MensajeObtenido = linea.Replace("MensajeObtenido:", "");
    }

    if (linea.Contains("DirectorioBase:"))
    {
        modelo.DirectorioBase = linea.Replace("DirectorioBase:", "");
    }
    return modelo;
}
```

Asumo que el tipo es 'Modelo', cámbialo por el que corresponde.

Espero te ayude